# Failed to execute 'updateIce' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Could not update the ICE Agent with the given configuration

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Hi I am currently working a video chat using webrtc and I have encounter an error when I try to use
`PeerConnection.updateIce(config)` it says

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'updateIce' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Could not update the ICE Agent with the given configuration.
>       at :1:4

```
var ICE_config= {
  'iceServers': [
    {
      'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
    },
    {
      'url': 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp',
      'credential': 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
      'username': '28224511:1379330808'
    },
    {
      'url': 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp',
      'credential': 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
      'username': '28224511:1379330808'
    }
  ]
}
var peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(ICE_config);
```

I update my iceServers

```
var new_ICE_config= {
  'iceServers': [
    {
      'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
    },... and so on
  ]
}

peerConnection.updateIce(iceServers);
```

Why does this error occur(s) didn't I pass the correct parameter for this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the updateIce method has never been properly implemented in Chrome, see [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4947) for one of the bugs about that. What is the reason you think you need to call updateIce?

You might want to create your peerconnection with TURN servers that work and that you operate instead of 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp' (and the other one). Those credentials originally come from [this html5rocks tutorial](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/#after-signaling-using-ice-to-cope-with-nats-and-firewalls) and have expired in September 2013

Comment: The reason I am using this method, is just to update the ice server(s) instead of re-establishing new peer connection again which will takes a lot of time because I have feature reconnect video or refresh look here https://gyazo.com/e9c81fd0779aad22a19e37659b9abbe1 and the ice server(s) I am using has limit of 20 sec(s) (TTL) and the previous ice server has been expired

I also try PeerConnection.setConfiguration() but it doesn't seem(s) recognize as a function

Comment: setConfiguration is only available in Chrome 58 and onward, see the issue linked. Until then you will need a longer TTL on the credentials.

Comment: so it does mean there's no solution for this other than finding an ice server(s) with longer TTL. okay, because `updateIce` is never been implemented properly and `setConfiguration` is still on experimental